# Java Spring Boot run failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I am new in Java Spring Boot. I am learning this through https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XpMXAxDN7mY&list=PLoSpJpNZs-onHvM-sluFGIYSoFzSgw6n9&index=9&t=14s.

After trying to run the app. I've got error like this

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'authController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in com.example.SimpleSpringSecurityProject.models.UserRepository defined in @EnableMongoRepositories declared on MongoRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableMongoRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoTemplate' while setting bean property 'mongoOperations'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDatabaseFactoryDependentConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mongoTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDatabaseFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDatabaseFactoryConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mongoDatabaseFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongo' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/MongoAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.mongodb.client.MongoClient]: Factory method 'mongo' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The connection string is invalid. Connection strings must start with either 'mongodb://' or 'mongodb+srv://
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor

SimpleSpringSecurityProjectApplication.java (main)

```
package com.example.SimpleSpringSecurityProject;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SimpleSpringSecurityProjectApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SimpleSpringSecurityProjectApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

UserModel.java

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Document(collection = "users")
public class UserModel {
    @Id
    private String id;

    private String username;

    private String password;

    public UserModel() {
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

UserRepository.java

```
package com.example.SimpleSpringSecurityProject.models;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<UserModel, String> {
    UserModel findByUsername(String username);
}
```

SecurityConfiguration.java

```
package com.example.SimpleSpringSecurityProject.configurations;

import com.example.SimpleSpringSecurityProject.services.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.NoOpPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userService);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/subs", "/auth").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }

    @Override
    protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManager();
    }
}
```

AuthController.java

```
package com.example.SimpleSpringSecurityProject;

import com.example.SimpleSpringSecurityProject.models.AuthenticationRequest;
import com.example.SimpleSpringSecurityProject.models.AuthenticationResponse;
import com.example.SimpleSpringSecurityProject.models.UserModel;
import com.example.SimpleSpringSecurityProject.models.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class AuthController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @PostMapping("/auth")
    private ResponseEntity<?> authenticateClient(@RequestBody AuthenticationRequest authenticationRequest) {
        String username = authenticationRequest.getUsername();
        String password = authenticationRequest.getPassword();

        try {
            authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password));
        } catch (BadCredentialsException ex) {
            return ResponseEntity.ok(new AuthenticationResponse("Error during client authentication"));
        }

        return ResponseEntity.ok(new AuthenticationResponse("Client authenticated: " + username));
    }

    @PostMapping("/subs")
    private ResponseEntity<?> subscribeClient(@RequestBody AuthenticationRequest authenticationRequest) {

        String username = authenticationRequest.getUsername();
        String password = authenticationRequest.getPassword();

        UserModel userModel = new UserModel();
        userModel.setUsername(username);
        userModel.setPassword(password);

        try {
            userRepository.save(userModel);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return ResponseEntity.ok(new AuthenticationResponse("Subscribe Success for client: " + username));
        }

        return ResponseEntity.ok(new AuthenticationResponse("Subscribe Success for client: " + username));
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
server.port=8682

spring.data.mongodb.uri="mongodb://localhost:27017/usersdb"
```

Can anyone help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errormessage is telling you everything you need to know:

> [com.mongodb.client.MongoClient]: Factory method 'mongo' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: **The connection string is invalid.** Connection strings must start with either 'mongodb://' or 'mongodb+srv:// at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor

From what I found with a [quick search](https://www.devglan.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-mongodb-configuration), try this: `spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://localhost:27017/usersdb`